# How to switch JS engine from SpiderMonkey to V8

Tags: cobalt

I have modified the `GetVariables()` method in my `gyp_configuration.py` file and ensured that the variables dictionary that is returned contains the following key/value pairs:

```
'javascript_engine': 'v8',
'cobalt_enable_jit': 1,
```

But I still can't switch JS engine from SpiderMonkey to V8 
How could we switch JS engine from SpiderMonkey to V8?

```
Cobalt version:RC(release candidate) of Cobalt 2019 LTS
build configuration: qa
platform:Linux/ARM
```

Comment: Hi there...  I'm surprised that this wasn't enough, these changes should have been sufficient.  Are you sure that elsewhere in your configuration they are not overridden?  As an example, you can look at the linux-x64x11 build which does have V8 enabled: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/19.lts.1+/src/starboard/linux/x64x11/

Please let me know if you are able to figure out what's wrong, I am curious if we would be able to make it easier to enable V8.

Comment: I don't know where there's a problem.The function GetVariables() has been modified as follows:

Comment: def GetVariables(self, configuration):
    hisi_home = self._GetHisiHome()
    sysroot = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(hisi_home, 'target'))
    if not os.path.isdir(sysroot):
      sys.exit(1)
    variables = super(HisiPlatformConfig, self).GetVariables(configuration)
    print(variables)
    variables.update({
        'clang': 0,
        'sysroot': sysroot,
        'javascript_engine': 'v8',
        'cobalt_enable_jit': 1,
    })
    print(variables)
    return variables

Comment: The printed log is  as follows:
{'cobalt_config': 'qa', 'cobalt_enable_jit': 0, 'use_tsan': 0, 'cobalt_fastbuild': 0, 'enable_vr': 0, 'use_asan': 0, 'javascript_engine': 'mozjs-45', 'custom_media_session_client': 0, 'clang': 0}
{'enable_vr': 0, 'use_tsan': 0, 'cobalt_config': 'qa', 'cobalt_enable_jit': 1, 'clang': 0, 'cobalt_fastbuild': 0, 'use_asan': 0, 'javascript_engine': 'v8', 'sysroot': '/opt/hisi-linux/x86-arm/arm-histbv320-linux/target', 'custom_media_session_client': 0}

Comment: Hi Eric, that seems right to me.  Adjusting the returned dictionary of GetVariables() affects the set of variables visible and acted upon by GYP.  Here is where the variables are checked: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/19.lts.1+/src/cobalt/script/engine.gyp#25 , perhaps you can play around with the values there to see if V8 is still being recognized?  If so, what is it that indicates to you that you are using SpiderMonkey instead of V8?